# How to remove log folder when uninstalling?

Tags: wcf, iis, wix, directory

I have WCF in IIS. WCF uses log4net logs. How I can remove log folder on uninstall? 
The log folder is in target folder.

I use this piece of code:

```
  <Directory Id='Logs' Name='Logs'>
    <Component Id="comp_iislogs" Guid="{0B0E2F6E-008D-42C9-8A7C-1F1265C077A1}"
      SharedDllRefCount="no" KeyPath="no" NeverOverwrite="no" Permanent="no" Transitive="no"
      Win64="no" Location="either">
      <RemoveFile Id="Files" On="uninstall" Name="*.log"></RemoveFile>
      <CreateFolder/>
    </Component>
  </Directory>
```

The problem is log file is in use on uninstallation and uninstaller says please stop app etc...

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to kill the process that has the logfile open then!  If that's something in a web app then you'll probably only have to recycle the application pool for the handle to be released (I think).

You can do that using `appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name: <pool name>` from within your WiX scripts.  You might want to actually stop then restart site however just to avoid any chances of it being open at the time.

Answer (score 0):

MSI removes only files it copied during initial installation.
Logs generated by the application are not recognized by the uninstall process. 
In other words, if at least one file exists in a directory to be removed, MSI will treat it as user file and skip its parent directory from removal.

In order to remove log directory you need to forcefully delete its contents first, but I would advise against that as you may encounter locking issues you don't want to deal with.

Comment: This piece of script can remove folder and files, but the problem is when it tries to do it log4net still uses log file. it is during the uninstallation process...

Answer (score 0):

Use [RemoveFolderEx](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_removefolderex.htm) element from Util extension in WiX.
With this approach, all the subdirectories and files are removed.

Example:

```
<util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" Property="Logs" />
```

Place this inside the Component tag.